# Fast update or create a table based on data from another table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table with 100k rows and 20 columns and I want based on that data to create a different table with the same amount of rows and columns, but with data calculated from the first table and previous columns of the second table.

Example:
Table A(with columns a1,a2,a3,a4,a5) is the table with original data.
Table B (with columns b1,b2,b3,b4,b5) is the second table with the calculated data.
What I would like to do is this (pseudocode - the calculations are more complicated):

```
UPDATE B 
SET    B.b2= A.a1*2,
       B.b3= A.a2*A.a1,
       B.b4= B.b1+B.b2,
       B.b5= round(B.b4,2)
WHERE  B.a1 = A.a1;
```

Another approach could be the CTAS (Create Table As Select) but this doesn't allow to create a column based on a previous column (I mean create B.b4 based on B.b3 at the same time)

Which is the faster approach to do it?

PS1. My approach to CTAS:

```
create table B NOLOGGING as
 select a1 b1,
    round(a2, 3) b2,
    a3 b3,
    b1+30 b4,  --ORA 00904 b1 invalid identifier
    a5 b5
 from A;
```

Comment: Have you considered a materialised view? Or even a normal view in this case? Or just adding the extra columns to the original table, as virtual columns? I'm not sure if you want the second table to stay in sync with the first one, or if it's a one-off snapshot of the data at a single point in time.

Comment: It is a one-off snapshot of the data. 
I am not familiar with the views. Could you please be more detailed?

Comment: But a one-off snapshot, or something you want to stay in sync - either updating immediately when the original changes (in which case why a separate table) or regularly? The `update` suggests it's not entirely one-off, of course...

Comment: I don't want to stay in sync. It is one time calculation.

Comment: Do you mean B.b4= B.b1+B.b2? I have tried it. It doesn't work. I get an error ORA 00904 B.b1 invalid identifier

Comment: I thought about re-doing the calculations each time. But I have complicated calculations for 20 columns. It is kind of stupid to do it like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do a CTAS without repeating the calculations you can use a subquery:

```
create table b (b1, b2, b3, b4, b5)
as
select t1, t2, t3, t1 + t2, round(t1 + t2, 2)
from (
  select a1 as t1, a1*2 as t2, a2 * a1 as t3
  from a
);
```

[SQl Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f26fd/1).

If you have multiple levels of dependency then you can have multiple levels of subquery, adding new calculated values at each level:

```
create table b (b1, b2, b3, b4, b5)
as
select t1, t2, t3, t4, round(t4, 2)
from (
  select t1, t2, t3, t1 + t2 as t4
  from (
    select a1 as t1, a1*2 as t2, a2 * a1 as t3
    from a
  )
);
```

[Another Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7c178/1).

You could use the same approach for an `update` or `merge`, but then you have two passes, one to insert the `b1` value on its own, then another to set everything else based on it. The CTAS approach will be quicker and simpler, I think.

Comment: Let me try this approach and I let you know. Thanks